# Magento relaunch: Migration of live and test databases

Tags: magento-1.7, database, migration

our agency has a local magento test environment. Database was a clone from a day XY in the past.

Since then, the old, live magento has got new customers, new orders.

Do you have some tips for migrating this databases?
Do you use any third-party tools and if yes, what tools do you prefer?

Thanks for your responses in advance!

Comment: Can't you backup the live site and restore it to your test site?

Answer (score 1):

You should never migrate a test database back into your Magento production database. For development and testing you can use a database dump from your production server.

All changes made to you development/test database should be scripted (for example like Magento does with the setup scripts). This way you can test the deployment of your changes multiple times (with a recent dump from production) before you publish your updates to your live/production server.

There is a (paid) 'Configuration Versioning' extension available that handles the creation of the setup scripts with the data changed. Another option is to use the MageFlow service, this also handles migration of changes between different setups.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best approach to this is to backup the PROD DB and distribute it among the developers obscuring the emails and passwords right before dumping it to avoid issues and false notifications while using the DB for testing.

There is a new paid extension I cant remember the name, it came out not long ago which handles this made by some community devs.